# Azure Databricks running Autoloader Implementation from java Jar throws org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException

Tags: java, azure, databricks, autoload

currently I am running into an issue but do not understand why this is happning. I have implemented a Java function which uses the Databricks Autoloader to readstream all parquet files from an azure blob storage and "write" it in a dataframe (Dataset because it is in Java written). The code is executed from an Jar which I build in **Java** and running as a Job on a Shared Cluster.

Code:

```
Dataset<Row> newdata= spark.readStream().format("cloudFiles")
        .option("cloudFiles.subscriptionId", storagesubscriptionid)
        .option("cloudFiles.format", "parquet")
        .option("cloudFiles.tenantId", sptenantid)
        .option("cloudFiles.clientId", spappid)
        .option("cloudFiles.clientSecret", spsecret)
        .option("cloudFiles.resourceGroup", storageresourcegroup)
        .option("cloudFiles.connectionString", storagesasconnectionstring)
        // .option("cloudFiles.useNotifications", "true")
        .schema(dfsample.schema()).option("cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles", "true").load(filePath);
newdata.show();
```

But unfortunatelly I get the following exception:

```
WARN SQLExecution: Error executing delta metering
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
cloudFiles
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.$anonfun$checkForBatch$1(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.$anonfun$checkForBatch$1$adapted(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:36)
```

What makes me wonder is, that the exactly same code is **running fine** inside a Databricks Notebook written in **Scala**:

```
val df1 = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").option("cloudFiles.useNotifications", "true").option("cloudFiles.subscriptionId", storagesubscriptionid)
.option("cloudFiles.format", "parquet")
.option("cloudFiles.tenantId", sptenantid)
.option("cloudFiles.clientId", spappid)
.option("cloudFiles.clientSecret", spsecret)
.option("cloudFiles.resourceGroup", storageresourcegroup)
.option("cloudFiles.connectionString", storagesasconnectionstring)
.option("cloudFiles.useNotifications", "true")
.option("cloudFiles.subscriptionId", storagesubscriptionid).schema(df_schema).option("cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles", "false").load(filePath);

display(df1);
```

I expect a Dataset object containing all the new data from the blobstorage parquet files in schema: id1:int, id2:int, content:binary

Comment: Hello Artur, 
You can't write a stream with a "load()". You need to use writeStream().

Comment: Hi Vincent by why did it work with scala: val df = spark.readstream..

Comment: @Vincent thanks i willl check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally, I have found a way to get Autoloader working inside my Java Jar.

As Vincent already commented you have to combine readstream with a writestream.

So I am simply writing the files which have been detected by the autoloader, to a Azure Data Lake.

```
    spark.readStream().format("cloudFiles")
            .option("cloudFiles.subscriptionId", STORAGE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
            .option("cloudFiles.format", "parquet")
            .option("cloudFiles.tenantId", SP_TENANT_ID)
            .option("cloudFiles.clientId", SP_APPLICATION_ID)
            .option("cloudFiles.clientSecret", SP_CLIENT_SECRET)
            .option("cloudFiles.resourceGroup", STORAGE_RESOURCE_GROUP)
            .option("cloudFiles.connectionString", STORAGE_SAS_CONNECTION_STRING)
            .option("cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles", "true")
            .option("cloudFiles.useNotifications", "true")
            .schema(DF_SCHEMA)
            .load(BLOB_STORAGE_LANDING_ZONE_PATH)
            .writeStream()
            .format("delta")
            .option("checkpointLocation", DELTA_TABLE_RAW_DATA_CHECKPOINT_PATH)
            .option("mergeSchema", "true")
            .trigger(Trigger.Once())
            .outputMode("append")
            .start(DELTA_TABLE_RAW_DATA_PATH).awaitTermination();
```

This works fine with Java when you need to run a Jar as Databricks Jobs.

But to be honest I am still wondering why, from inside a Notebook, I don't have to use writestream in scala language to receive new files from the autoloader.